# I want to know how to open a workbook in VBA with a variable name

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to open an excel workbook in a macro that has a constant name, a variable date and a variable suffix consisting of letters and numbers. For instance.

"Allpostings_041616_big232.xlsx" could be the file name for April 16th

On April 17th the file might look like this

"Allpostings_041716_agd214.xlsx"

If I wanted to choose the file for tody's date in my macro, how would I code this in VBA?

Comment: Is there only one file per day?

Comment: How to construct the "variable suffix consisting of letters and numbers"?

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim P(1 To 5) As String

    P(1) = "C:\TestFolder\"
    P(2) = "Allpostings_"
    P(3) = Format(Now(), "mmddyy") & "_"
    P(4) = "big232.xlsx"
    s = Join(P, "")

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=s
End Sub
```

Just edit the `P(4)` line to meet your needs.

**EDIT#1:**

If all the possible files are contained within a single folder and all have files have the same name schema, then here is a way to find the correct file to open:

1. use a `Dir()` loop to gather all the file names
2. scan the list of filenames for the correct date field
3. input the found file

Comment: Thank you Gary! My only concern is that the P(4) part will always be variable and I will not know in advance what the change will be. How can I write the code to "accept" whatever P(4) will be? Thanks again!

Comment: @LouM.........How you YOU, *(the human)* determine what `P(4)` should be **???**

Comment: @LouM  See my **EDIT#1** for a possible method

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

```
Sub test()
    workbookopen ("big232")
    workbookopen ("agd214")
End Sub

Function workbookopen(lastpart As String)
    ChDir ("C:\work\")
    Files = Dir("*.xlsx")
    Do While Files <> ""
        If Files = "Allpostings_" & Format(Now(), "mmddyy") & "_" & lastpart & ".xlsx" Then
            Workbooks.Open (Files) '"Allpostings_" & Format(Now(), "mmddyy") & "_" & lastpart & ".xlsx"
        End If
        Files = Dir
    Loop
End Function
```